# Canvas equivalent for mobile - or alternatively SSO from native FB app to mobile web app

Tags: facebook, mobile, mobile-website, facebook-canvas

We are building a Facebook app, for both desktop and mobile. 
In the App Settings, We set up a canvas url, and a Mobile Site URL.

- I can access the canvas page fine from the desktop: apps.facebook.com/myapp
- When accessing this url (apps.facebook.com/myapp) from a mobile browser, I am redirected to the Mobile Site URL, which is the intended behaviour.
- When accessing this app from the native Facebook mobile app, I am also redirected to the Mobile Site URL.

My questions are:
- Ideally: is there a way to run our mobile app from within the native mobile Facebook app (say in a webview), the same way that built-in apps, such as "Chat", "Like Pages", "Find Friends", "Notes", etc, work ? Then the user experience would be similar to the canvas page on desktop.

- Failing that, is there a way to automatically authenticate the users when they are redirected to our mobile app ? 
  I understand from the following document:
  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/22/driving-mobile-app-installs-with-the-app-center/
  that SSO is only available with native apps, not with web apps, but as this document dates from last year, I want to be sure it is still relevant.

I understand that we can auto-login users on the mobile web app (using the JS SDK) if they are logged in facebook in the browser, but we assume that if they are using the FB native app, they are unlikely to be logged in their browser, and we would really like to avoid this additional login step.

Thanks !